# Is there a way to add a while loop in DB2?

Tags: loops, db2

I currently have a query set up through Unions [code block 1] to gather data. It works properly, but very inefficient to have it repeat that many times

Is there a way to convert this to a while loop in DB2?

I've tried to write a while loop in [Code Block 2] but it doesn't work in DB2.

I keep getting a syntax error in Code_block_2

In code block 2, I want to add 1 to the start and end date variables so the next query will run with new time periods (stored as integers) eg 1st time will be between 201601 and 201701, the second time will be between 201602 and 201702. I tried to set the end_dt to print with each row of data

The union method works, but I have to write the same chunk of code a bunch of times. A loop would be more effective

[code block 1 - Union (Works)]

```
select
  1 as a.period,
  a.name,
  a.date
from
  data_table
where
  month between 201601 and 201701
union
select
  1 as period,
  a.name,
  a.date
from
  data_table a
where
  a.month between 201602 and 201702 -- this is changing in a consistent pattern
union
select
  1 as period,
  a.name,
  a.date
from
  data_table a
where
  a.month between 201603 and 201703
```

[Code block 2 - with loop attempt]

```
Begin atomic
declare @end_dt integer default 201701;
declare @start_dt integer default 201601;
while @end_dt < 201712  do 
   --statement
   select
     @end_dt as period,
     a.name,
     a.date
   from
     data_table a
   where
      month between @start_dt and @end_dt;
-- add + 1 to variables
set @end_dt = @end_dt +1;
set @start_dt = @start_dt +1;
end while;
end;
```

here is an example data set

(In data base)

> name - date 
>   Jane - 5/2/2016 
>   Jim - 6/3/2016 
>   Zack - 1/1/2016 
>   Jill - 5/1/2016 
>   Joe - 1/1/2016 
>   James - 4/1/2016 
>   Zoe - 2/2/2016

Output (Expected, and result of code block 1.)

> Period - Name - date 
>   201701 - Jane - 5/2/2016 
>   201701 - Jim - 6/3/2016 
>   201701 - Zack - 1/1/2016 
>   201701 - Jill - 5/1/2016 
>   201701 - Joe - 1/1/2016 
>   201701 - James - 4/1/2016 
>   201701 - Zoe - 2/2/2016 
>   201702 - Jane - 5/2/2016 
>   201702 - Jim - 6/3/2016 
>   201702 - Jill - 5/1/2016 
>   201702 - James - 4/1/2016 
>   201702 - Zoe - 2/2/2016

-- notice how the 1/1/2016 dates trickle off the set in 201702 period 
I'm not 100% sure on the version of DB2, But it's consistent with
DB2 for Linux Unix and Windows 10.5
and z/OS

Comment: Do you understand that your ranges are overlapping? Why don't you just use a single range that includes all of them?

Comment: I'm sure the ranges should be overlapping. This helps getting the year-to-date totals for that period. For example, If the month is 201701, I want the activity to include the last 12 months.

Comment: But you're losing all those values with the UNION or with the lack of an aggregation.

Comment: If those values are being lost with a union. Should I just run the query over a large range and calculate the YTD totals another way?

Comment: I have a problem with your date range - it's an inclusive upper bound.  You're getting 13 months (1 year, 1 month), instead of 12 months (1 year), which seems wrong.  You _should_ be using an explicit, exclusive upper-bound - `<` - especially if you ever plan on using day-of-month.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following query as is.
Is this a "virtual" table `range` you are looking for?

```
with t(n, m) as (
select 1, date(to_date(201601, 'YYYYMM')) from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
select n+1, m + 1 month
from t 
where n<11
)
, range (start, end) as (
select year(m)*100+month(m) as start, year(m + 1 year)*100+month(m + 1 year) as end
from t
)
select start, end
from range r;
```

If yes, then you can join this `range` table with your `data_table` on the `a.month between r.start and r.end` condition to get the result you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a date dim / calendar table on the system?

If not, I just put in a values table. This can be changed to whatever you need. It just needs to have a list of YYYYMM date values over the period you want.

```
select
  dates.period,
  a.name,
  a.date
from
  table( values 
         (201701)
,(201702)
,(201703)
,(201704)
,(201705)
,(201706)
,(201707)
,(201708)
,(201709)
,(201710)
,(201711)
,(201712)
) date(period)
join
  data_table
    on a.month between (date.period - 100) and date.period
```